# Recorrer todas las posiciones de la matriz con 4 bucles

Tags: java, matrices

Estoy intentando lo siguiente:   Recorrer todas las posiciones (no elementos) de un matriz. Lo normal para recorrer una matriz se suele hacer con dos for, pero en este caso quiero obtener lo de dos, es decir.
En la matriz de posiciones

```
00 01 02 03
10 11 12 13
20 21 22 23
```

Un for que genere la posicion 00 y luego otro que genere las posiciones del resto de la matriz. 01, 02, 03, 10, 11, 12, 13, 20, 21, 22, 23.
De ahi, pasaria a la posicion 01, en la que compara con  00, 02, 03, 10, 11, 12, 13, 20, 21, 22, 23.
No se si enlazando 4 bucles de tipo for es la forma mas directa, por que creo que seria sobrecargar un poco el metodo. O igual es necesario recursividad, pero suele ser poco recomendable pero a veces la solucion mas directa.
¿Alguien puede indicarme cual es la solucion mas correcta?

Tengo un metodo que si encuentra elementos repetidos 3 veces o mas por columna, coviente esos elementos a 0. El usuario intercambia las posiciones de la matriz, para formar ese bloque de 3 o mas.
Entonces yo lo que quiero es un metodo que antes de que el usuario introduzca la entrada para intercambiar los elementos, comprobar si va a poder hacer el movimiento. Por eso, comprobando todas las posibles entradas que introduzca el usuario, puedo determinar si hay o no hay.
El usuario solo puede hacer movimientos e intercambiar arriba, abajo, derecha o izquierda. El metodo de intercambiar ya lo tengo yo realizado

Para la posicion 12 el usuario solo podria introducir 02 22 11 13 que seria cuando se intercambiarian. Luego comprueba si hace el bloque. Si no se hace bloque, devuelve la matriz como estaba. Solo las posiciones de abajo son itercambiables con la del centro.

```
   02
11 12 13
   22
```

**Resumen**
El codigo que tengo (no me lo hace bien todas con todas)

```
public static void genera(int[][] matriz) {
        boolean hay = true;
        for (int fil = 0; fil < lado; fil++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < lado; col++) {
                for (int fil1 = 0; fil < ladoh; fil1++) {
                    for (int col1 = 0; col1 < ladoh; col1++) {
                        if (contiguo(fil, col, fil1, col1) == true) {
                            bloque(matriz, lado);
                            hay = hayCeros(matriz);
                            System.out.println(hay);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

metodos bloque, comprueba si hay 3 o mas. hay ceros, mira si el metodo bloque ha convertido a ceros (por que se dan las circunstancias).

Comment: Con los 2 clásicos ciclos FOR imprimes los valores: matriz(#fila, #columna), seguido de esto lo que quieres es por otro lado con los mismos 2 ciclos FOR imprimir la matriz pero con los indices (posiciones) lo cual seria algo como: #fila+""+#columna... Eso es lo que entiendo de tu párrafo inicial, seguiré viéndolo jeje

Comment: varias cosas.. porque la recursividad es poco recomendable? no entiendo porque haces 4 for.. sabes que le podes hacer trampa al for no? el iterador puede ser modificado adentro de la iteracion... igual, otra cosa que me genera duda es.. cuando hace un cambio, no puede quedar la matriz invalida por el cambio? con lo cual, no es mas facil en lugar de comprobar toda la matriz, ir verificando que no haya posiciones erroneas al momento del cambio con sus adyacentes?

Comment: No me gusta gastale trampas al iterador del for. Si se convierten en ceros algun elemento, eso es que hay movimiento posible (comprobando de que sea valido el movimiento que realiza). Y todavia no lo he acabado, doy al metodo una copia de la matriz, no la original.

Comment: entonces usa un while y no le vas a hacer trampas a nadie...

Comment: Solo he recorrido matrices con for, con while seria poner los contadores fuera e ir con bastante cuidado de inicializarles y me genera lio recorrer asi matrices, (si es que es la unica opcion hacerlo con while).

Comment: entonces tenes una confusion grande. En un for estas inicializando el contador, lo estas incrementando, y estas controlando el final, solo que lo haces todo en una sola linea. Lo que comentas de tu problema, puede que sea mas facil de resolver en un bloque while, sobre todo por la forma en que queres resolverlo.

Comment: Pero en algun momento dicho contador voy a tener que hacer que valga 0. Con los for ya me lo resuelve el, aunque ya se el problema, el ultimo for deja de actuar cuando ya llega al ultimo. No se, lo que busco es simplicidad y eficiencia, y no se si de este modo se consigue

Comment: y no.. hacer 4 for no parece eficiente de seguro (igual hay que probarlo)

Comment: Si, bueno a eso es una parte para introducir lo que estoy intentando hacer, pero no me soluciona el problema.

Comment: Esta probado. Te puedo poner todo el codigo, con main y todo y hasta su salida si quieres. Creo que por eso he puesto en la pregunta no me lo hace bien todas con todas. En ningun momento he dicho no que no haya probado, digo que es la unica solucion que se me ocurre, aparte de la recursion, de la cual ya mencione antes.

Comment: no. no pongas todo el codigo, si quieres que lo reproduzcamos pon un [mcve].

Comment: Con todo el codgo, me refiero a que lo he sacado del programa principal solo los metodos que actuan, cosa que viene a decir la pagina esa que ya habia visitado.

Comment: El codigo que esta aca no es [mcve]. Si yo lo pego dentro de un progama, no hace nada y no reproduce tu problema. Esto es solamente un fragmento de tu codigo. Para poder ayudarte, tenes que ser mas claro con el problema y mas claro con el codigo que aportas de ejemplo.

Comment: Pero de todas formas, pongo el codigo del metodo que es el que me da problemas, me dices que tengo que hacerlo con while, luego un ejemplo minimo y despues que le ponga el codigo del minimo (150 lineas) que reproducen el fallo? Ahora igual me dices que no lo ponga todo el codigo que es mucho y que vuelva a hacerlo cuando es lo minimo con lo que funcionar...

Comment: a ver.. no.. nos estamos confundiendo. No puedo probar tu codigo. No tengo una matriz, ni el resto del programa que reproduzca en que casos "no me lo hace bien". Para saber que casos no lo hace bien, deberias indicar datos de entrada, de salida y la salida mala. por lo que estas diciendo, esto se soluciona mas facil si haces un trace a mano de como va la funcion, hasta que veas porque algunos casos fallan. de otra manera, el codigo "parece" bien, y no podemos hacer mucho mas.